# How does torchvision.transforms.Normalize operate?

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I don't understand how the normalization in `Pytorch` works.

I want to set the mean to `0` and the standard deviation to `1` across all columns in a tensor `x` of shape `(2, 2, 3)`.

A simple example:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
                       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]],

                       [[ 7.,  8.,  9.],
                        [10., 11., 12.]]])

>>> norm = transforms.Normalize((0, 0), (1, 1))
>>> norm(x)
tensor([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
         [ 4.,  5.,  6.]],

        [[ 7.,  8.,  9.],
         [10., 11., 12.]]])
```

So nothing has changed when applying the normalization transform. Why is that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To give an answer to your question, you've now realized that [`torchvision.transforms.Normalize`](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.Normalize.html) doesn't work as you had anticipated. That's because it's not meant to:

- ***normalize***: (making your data range in `[0, 1]`) nor
- ***standardize***: making your data's `mean=0` and `std=1` (which is what you're looking for.

The operation performed by `T.Normalize` is merely a shift-scale transform:

> ```
> output[channel] = (input[channel] - mean[channel]) / std[channel]
> ```

The parameters names `mean` and `std` which seems rather misleading knowing that it is not meant to refer to the desired *output* statistics but instead *any arbitrary values*. That's right, if you input `mean=0` and `std=1`, it will give you `output = (input - 0) / 1 = input`. Hence the result you received where function `norm` had no effect on your tensor values when you were expecting to get a tensor of mean and variance `0` and `1`, respectively.

However, providing the correct `mean` and `std` parameters, *i.e.* when `mean=mean(data)` and `std=std(data)`, then you end up calculating the [*z-score*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) of your data channel by channel, which is what is usually called *'standardization'*. So in order to actually get `mean=0` and `std=1`, you first need to compute the mean and standard deviation of your data.

If you do:

```
>>> mean, std = x.mean(), x.std()
(tensor(6.5000), tensor(3.6056))
```

It will give you the global average, and global standard deviation respectively.

Instead, what you want is to measure the 1st and 2nd order statistics *per*-channel. Therefore, we need to apply [`torch.mean`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mean.html) and [`torch.std`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mean.html) on all dimensions expect `dim=1`. Both of those functions can receive a *tuple* of dimensions:

```
>>> mean, std = x.mean((0,2)), x.std((0,2))
(tensor([5., 8.]), tensor([3.4059, 3.4059]))
```

The above is the correct mean and standard deviation of `x` measured along each channel. From there you can go ahead and use `T.Normalize(mean, std)` to correctly transform your data `x` with the correct shift-scale parameters.

```
>>> norm(x)
tensor([[[-1.5254, -1.2481, -0.9707],
         [-0.6934, -0.4160, -0.1387]],

        [[ 0.1387,  0.4160,  0.6934],
         [ 0.9707,  1.2481,  1.5254]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the explanation on [documentation of torchvision.transforms.Normalize](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Normalize):

> Normalize a tensor image with mean and standard deviation. Given mean:
> (mean[1],...,mean[n]) and std: (std[1],..,std[n]) for n channels, this
> transform will normalize each channel of the input torch.*Tensor i.e.,
> output[channel] = (input[channel] - mean[channel]) / std[channel]

So if you have `mead=0` and `std=1` then `output=(output - 0) / 1` will not change.

Example to show above explanation:

```
from torchvision import transforms
import torch

norm = transforms.Normalize((0,0),(1,2))
x = torch.tensor([[[1.0,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])
out = norm(x)
print(x)
print(out)
```

Outputs:

```
tensor([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],  
         [ 4.,  5.,  6.]], 

        [[ 7.,  8.,  9.],  
         [10., 11., 12.]]])
tensor([[[1.0000, 2.0000, 3.0000], 
         [4.0000, 5.0000, 6.0000]],

        [[3.5000, 4.0000, 4.5000],
         [5.0000, 5.5000, 6.0000]]])
```

As you can see, the first channel is not change and second channel is divide by
2.